# width is ignored (basic html)

Tags: html, css

```html
<body>
  <div style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:200px;bottom:100%;background:#aeaeae;"></div>
  <div style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:200px;width:calc(100% - 200px);bottom:100%;background:#ffffff;"></div>
</body>
```

Why are widths rendering as 0px (on chrome)??

this is very simple HTML / CSS code

Comment: I don't see the widths rendering as "0px".

Comment: you have no height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `width` of these elements is not rendering as `0px` in Chrome; the `height` is. You haven't defined any reason for these elements to be taller than `0px`.

If you change your `bottom: 100%` rule to be `bottom: 0`, your element will stretch from the top to the bottom of its parent.

```html
<body>
  <div style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:200px;bottom:0;background:#aeaeae;"></div>
  <div style="position:absolute;top:0;left:200px;width:calc(100% - 200px);bottom:0;background:#ffffff;"></div>
</body>
```